# Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml is also present at [:barcodescanner:] AndroidManifest.xml value=(true)

Tags: android, android-manifest, ionic3

I’m trying to set the allowBackup attribute in my ionic 3 app manifest to false but gradle complains with the following error:

Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:18-45 is also present at [:barcodescanner:] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-11:19 to override.

To Set allowBackup=false using below line in config.xml file

```
<platform name="android"> <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge"> <application android:allowBackup="false"/> </edit-config> </platform>
```

I use Barcode Scanner in my ionic 3 app.(Repo: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner recommended in https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/)

please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler to ignore the attribute from the external library. The way to do that is to add this line in application tag:

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

PS: To access the tools add **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** in the manifest tag at the top.

Comment: Tested and works here - thanks much for this - No clue how I could have solved it otherwise.

Comment: i have got same error while adding flutter_zoom_sdk packages , and after adding ---> tools:replace="android:allowBackup" i got another error which is in below  ---- > tools:replace specified at line:14 for attribute android:allowBack, but no new value specified