# not build with nxp library TapLinx?

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ex5">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **Manifest merger failed**: Attribute `application@allowBackup` `value=(true)` from AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-35
>           is also present at [:nxp] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-36 `value=(false)`.
>           Suggestion: add '`tools:replace="android:allowBackup"`' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

what is it?

Comment: i solved delete 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"'=(true)  from my manifest

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48233016/6630837)